# Number of subsequences of length 3 or more, such that the sum of its "middle" is equal to the values of its "endpoints"

Tags: python, algorithm, subsequence

> Given an array of integers (length N), return the count of subsequences of length at least 3 (from 3 to N) such that the following conditions hold: the value of the first element of the subsequence equals the value of the last element of the subsequence, and they both equal the sum of the values of the 'middle' elements of the subsequence, i.e., excluding the first and last elements.
>
> You are not allowed to sort or change the sequence of the array of integers in any way.

What would be a more effective way to solve the problem than the following "naive" approach?

```
def count_balanced_subsegments(capacity):
    n = len(capacity)
    count = 0

    prefix_sum = [0] * n
    prefix_sum[0] = capacity[0]

    # Calculate the prefix sum of the capacity array
    for i in range(1, n):
        prefix_sum[i] = prefix_sum[i - 1] + capacity[i]

    for i in range(n - 2):  # Start from the first server
        for j in range(i + 2, n):  # Try all possible subsegment lengths starting from 3
            if capacity[i] == capacity[j] and prefix_sum[j - 1] - prefix_sum[i] == capacity[i]:
                count += 1

    return count

# Example usage:
capacity = [9, 3, 3, 3, 9]
result = count_balanced_subsegments(capacity)
print(result)  # Output should be 2
```

Comment: Your code isn't correct, for example for input [1, 1, 2, 1] it fails to count the subsequence [1, 1, 1]. And that's misleading answerers.

Comment: if non-contiguous subsequences are allowed, this problem is as hard as subset-sum, which is NP hard.
That's unlikely for an "algorithm question" in which usually there is something better to do than brute forcing it, but for subset-sum there isn't really

Answer (score 2):

We can store prefix sums in dictionary together with item value as tuple key`(psum, a[i])`. Value for this key is the number of correponding prefix sums.

For every new value `a[i]` we check that difference `psum - a[i]` already is stored in dictionary (analog of yours `prefix_sum[j - 1] - prefix_sum[i] == capacity[i]`) with border value equal to `a[i]`, and update counter if such sums do exist.

Delay of dictionary update (`last` tuple storing) is intended to provide subsize>=3 condition

Time is linear, ~50 milliseconds for list size 100 000

```
from collections import defaultdict
def cnt_balanced(a):
    n = len(a)
    count = 0
    psum = a[0]
    last = (psum,a[0])
    sums = defaultdict(int)

    for i in range(1, n):
        t = (psum - a[i], a[i])
        if t in sums:
            count += sums[t]

        sums[last] += 1
        psum += a[i]
        last = (psum, a[i])

    return count
```

Comment: I'd definitely do the linear time one. I thought that's what you were going to do after reading just your first sentence. Not just more efficient but also simpler/less code.

Comment: @KellyBundy Done ;)

Comment: Reading it now, looks similar to [mine](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RZBNCsIwEIVxmxu4m2WrLfizsUJXLgUvIF3ImGKgTcJ0IvQsbtzooTyNTWNqyOZ98_KGvMfb9nwz-vl8Oa7z3Wc2r8m0gKZpJLIyugPVWkMMB-M0SxLiKms4yqbpE7zYCyru072A4SATlNGXpCPrXDuwVZj7yaQsyfsgTkbLUdeGAEFpiKkhNIYsS8AJhCSPmM6YeUO-WWD1NwzcL6i8aT3h387wYqQk2ZEOgUJYUpqT8LlzkcE23qJK09DQr6hY2Bc).

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes. Counter usage looks somewhat simpler.

Comment: Btw the "almost-linear" code is *quadratic* on `[0] * N`.

Comment: @KellyBundy  Yes, I know

Comment: Ok. Wasn't clear, since it was linear on your own earlier example of alternating 1 and -1 (because  `psum - a[i] in sums` is never true there).

Comment: Since you're also an experienced algorithm/ math person: Have you ever seen a definition of "subsequence" like the OP is interpreting it? I don't think I have in 25 years of computer science, coding competitions, coding sites, and math. And I think I would've noticed, since I realized early on that apparently *everybody* defines it the same. I have seen plenty of *individuals* confusing subsequence and substring (for example when asking questions here), but never saw a *definition* deviating from the standard.

Comment: @KellyBundy Problem statement it doesn't define "subsequence" . Do you think this is a "trap" ? - with example showing only contiguous (subarray) , but real tests might involve something like 4 2 1 2 7 4 ? In this case I got caught too - seeing at code and not rereading statement...

Comment: I don't think the actual problem setter intentionally made it a "trap" with that example, that would be somewhat evil. I tried googling the problem statement to see the full original, but found it only here. Waiting for the OP to respond. On the one hand, their example isn't in the quote, so I'd expect the OP made it up themself and subsequence is meant the standard way (because it's just such a strong standard) and the OP got it wrong. On the other hand, the linear algorithm for their interpretation is so pretty that that might just be really the intention :-)

Comment: @PeterBilko Is my answer still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

One potential to speed-up the computation is to compute the combinations between indices of equal value.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def count_balanced_subsegments_2(capacity):
    indices, prefix_sum = {}, []

    cnt = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(capacity):
        indices.setdefault(v, []).append(i)
        prefix_sum.append(cnt := cnt + capacity[i])

    count = 0
    for k, v in indices.items():
        for i, j in combinations(v, 2):
            if j - i >= 2 and prefix_sum[j - 1] - prefix_sum[i] == capacity[i]:
                count += 1

    return count
```

---

Quick benchmark, with N = 50_000 and values between 1 and 10:

```py
from random import randint, seed
from timeit import timeit

seed(42)
capacity = [randint(1, 10) for _ in range(50_000)]

assert count_balanced_subsegments(capacity) == count_balanced_subsegments_2(capacity)

t1 = timeit("count_balanced_subsegments(capacity)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("count_balanced_subsegments_2(capacity)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"{t1=}")
print(f"{t2=}")
```

Prints:

```
t1=28.380160036991583
t2=5.308306446007919
```