# Find the number of special subarray such that the bitwise XOR of first and last element is equal to XOR of all the other elements in the subarray

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor

Given an array of integers, find the number of subarray which has length at least 3 where the bitwise XOR of first and last element in the subarray is equal to rest of the elements in the subarray. Can you think of a solution better than O(N^2)

I came up with O(n^2) solution using prefix_array. I was wondering if there is optimal solution than this because my solution cannot pass the last couple test cases.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant "the bitwise XOR of first and last element in the subarray is equal to the bitwise XOR to all other elements in the subarray".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If bitwise XOR of two edge elements is equal to XOR of inner elements, then XOR of entire subarray is zero.

So you can calculate prefix XOR sums, put them in dictionary, and "on the fly" check if proper pair sum already already exists in the dictionary.

[Look at alike problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77185683/844416) (usual sums, nor XOR), also contains size>=3 trick

Comment: `and "on the fly" check if proper pair sum already already exists in the dictionary` can you explain this statement, I am not able to understand this

Comment: @technotigr  [5 3 2 1 7]  xor prefix sums [5 6 4 5 6] for the second 5 we already have sum 5, so [3 2 1] sublist is candidate for special sublist (we have to check also borders  3^1 vs inner 4^6)

Comment: `so [3 2 1] sublist is candidate for special sublist (we have to check also borders 3^1 vs inner 4^6)`  can you explain this more please

Comment: @technotigr Two equal prefix sums tell us that sublist between corresponding items has zero xor sum  - is it clear?

Comment: One last question `we have to check also borders 3^1 vs inner 4^6` why to check this? we already have the special sublist [3,2,1]

Comment: @technotigr Aha, my mistake in comments, it is not needed, any part of zero-sum sublist gives zero sum with the rest of sublist.

Comment: Great insight. The algorithm works in O(n)!